# CBC KEY recovery when KEY=IV

Tags: aes, cbc, initialization-vector, padding-oracle

We have access to an encryption and decryption server with the following implementation. How can we get the secret key by interacting with this server?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

KEY = ?

def encrypt(plaintext):
    if len(plaintext)%16 != 0:
        return {"False"}

    cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, KEY)
    encrypted = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)
    return {"ciphertext": encrypted.hex()}


def decrypt(ciphertext):
    cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, KEY)
    if len(ciphertext)%16 != 0:
        return {"False"}
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext)
    try:
        decrypted.decode()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return {"False"}
    return {"True"}
```

As we can see in the code, IV=KEY which is a vulnerability. The server also checks padding/decryption and returns True/False. I suspect this implementation is vulnrable to Padding Oracle Attack, but i still don't know how to get the KEY with these information. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your guess is of course probably right, as you don't seem to have all that much information otherwise.  But you haven't indicated where you are stuck given this information. Have you tried to implement the padding oracle attack already?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If i want to use padding oracle attack i have to find plaintext from a ciphertext by changing bits from last position but i already have the plaintext so i dont know how would i use this attack to find KEY!

Comment: You can also use a plaintext oracle attack, but if a padding oracle attack is possible then that would be easier. There is a `UnicodeDecodeError` after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two hints:

- How can you craft a chosen plaintext so that the encryption will tell you the value of $E_k(k)$?
- Given the value of $E_k(k)$, how can you craft a chosen ciphertext so that the decryption will tell you the value of $k$?  How can you make sure that the padding is valid (so that you don't get a decryption failure)?

Comment: I couldnt figure out what you mean. Can you explain?

Comment: @Sahar: do you know what processing is done during CBC mode encryption?  In CBC mode decryption?

Comment: of course yes i know.

Comment: @Sahar: ok, then, during encryption, how is the first ciphertext block generated?

Comment: C1 = enc(KEY, P1 XOR KEY)

Comment: @Sahar: Ok, then, how do we select a plaintext (P1) so that we can learn the value $enc(KEY, KEY)$?

Comment: if P1 is all zero then we get enc(KEY, KEY)

Comment: omg so after we get C1 in the above step (which in this case we can say that IV is the message and P1 which is all zero is the IV since x XOR y is same as y XOR x) then we can do padding oracle attack to reconstruct IV which is the key. Am i right?

Comment: @Sahar: well, yes, I suppose you could use a padding oracle attack - however, there is a far more efficient way (things get a *lot* easier for the attacker when there is no MAC).

Comment: Thanks for your help i really appreciate it. One last question, what is the more efficient way?

Comment: @Sahar: using the value $E_k(k)$, you craft a ciphertext so that the decryption tells you the value $k$.  Note that the padding has to be correct (so you get the decrypted plaintext and not a decryption failure).  To do that, consider the processing during CBC mode decryption...

Comment: but the decrypt function does not return the plaintext, it only returns True/Flase so i guess the only solution to find the key is by performing padding oracle attack.

Comment: @Sahar: oops, I see you're correct - the decryptor only returns a boolean.  In that case, the padding attack is the best you can do...